# How can I make my randomly generated word stay the same?

Tags: ruby

`enter code here`I'm making a simple word guessing game, but every time I submit my player guess the random word changes. I've tried a lot of solutions, but my submission form for the guess always refreshes the secret word. 
Any suggestions? Thanks!

P.S sorry for my disgusting code formatting

Here is my code:

```
formulate_secret(@@codeword)
@vmessage = "Welcome to Wheel of Fortune! To begin, type a letter:"
@results = "..."

while @@tries > 1
  player_guess = params[:guess].to_s
  eval_guess(player_guess)
  break
end

erb :home, :locals => {:message => @message, :tries => @@tries, :response => response, :words => @words, :codeword => @@codeword, :vmessage => @vmessage, :wordtable => @wordtable, :guess => player_guess, :result => @results}
end

@@correct = false
@vmessage = ""
@results = ""
wordtable = []
@@tries = 10
@result = []
@@codeword = ""

def read_secret
  wordtable = Array.new
  file = File.open("wordfile.txt") 
  File.foreach("wordfile.txt") { |line| 
    line = line.strip
    wordtable.push line }
  file.close()
  @wordtable = wordtable
end

def formulate_secret(codeword)
  read_secret
  @result = []
  5.times do
    @result << @wordtable[rand(@wordtable.length)]
  end
  @@codeword = @result.sample
end

def eval_guess(player_guess)
  @results = "#{@@codeword}"

  if player_guess == "".to_s
    ""
  elsif 
    player_guess == @@codeword
    @results = "Congrats you did it!"
    @@correct = true
  elsif player_guess != @@codeword && !player_guess.nil?
    @results = ""
    @@tries -= 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Please next time ident your code, if not it's hard to read it

Comment: Why, in read_secret, do you have File.open and File.foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to get you started. Please note that each function does only one thing. One creates the word list and the other returns a word from the word list. I helps if you can encapsulate one thing/action in a function.

```
def createWordList(filename)

  words = []
  # Make sure filename exists as a file
  File.foreach(filename){|line|
    words.push(line.chomp)
  }

  words

end

def getRandWord(words)

  words.sample

end


print "Enter filename: "
filename = gets.chomp

puts getRandWord(createWordList(filename))
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate you taking the time out of your day to lend a helping hand